# Obter numero de computadores que estão utilizando o sistema em rede

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um software e o cliente só poderá utilizar o sistema em uma determinada quantidade de computadores por vez. Gostaria de saber como obtenho o numero de maquinas que estão com o sistema aberto a cada vez que um computador tente abrir o sistema. Caso a quantidade de computadores abertos ultrapasse o limite(Quantidade de computadores varia com a licença de uso que o cliente adquire ao comprar o sistema), o sistema não irá abrir.

Comment: Tem um servidor central para quem os clientes possam comunicar? Ou a aplicação e `standalone`?

Comment: Tem um servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Depende da sua implementação.

Caso você esteja utilizando conexões TCP/IP diretas, é fácil: Monitore a coleção de conexões, e negue novas conexões se o valor alcançar o máximo previsto.

Caso esteja utilizando conexões não permanentes, você precisará implementar algum tipo de controle de sessões ativas.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você deverá armazenar em algum lugar a quantidade que está em uso (database, arquivo texto, ou algo do tipo). Quando o usuário clicar em sair, você decrementa a quantidade. Um outro meio seria implementar o Heartbeat pattern também:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8349/Observing-Applications-via-Heartbeat